# Executing a function over a grouped set

Tags: excel, charts

I have two columns of data in Excel, one containing dates and the other values 1 or 2 which represent a specific status (like an enum).

Here is an example data set:

```
2014/07/04  | 1
2014/07/04  | 1
2014/07/04  | 2
2014/07/04  | 1
2014/07/05  | 2
2014/07/06  | 1
2014/07/06  | 1
2014/07/06  | 2
```

I need to get a graph of the percentages of the number 1 over days; in the above example

- July 4th: 75%
- July 5th: 100%
- July 6th: 66%.

I've tried pivot tables and charts with no luck because I can't write my own function for values (`COUNTIF` for ones divided by `COUNT`), only use the predefined ones which aren't of any use.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Can you add your column data as formatted text in your question, instead of an image?

Comment: Of course, my apologies as I'm not familiar with the etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a pivot chart.

I made up my own data so it doesn't quite match but it is the same idea.

For the pivot table fields I used

Legend Fields:Compare
Axis Fields:Date
Values: Count of compare

For values under Value field settings goto show value as and change this to % of column total and summarize value by Count.

If you only want to see number one just put a filter on the column labels.

[image]

Comment: Almost there. the values should be `% of Row Total` not `% of Column Total`

Comment: It was indeed % of Row Total. After playing with it a bit I got what I needed. Many thanks to both!